# Android OutofMemory with ObjecOutputStream

Tags: android, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I have created a client/server pair with two threads to send and receive objects, While it runs fine at the beginning I'm experiencing an OutofMemory error when it runs for a while, I was looking out how te garbage collector works in Android 2.3.4 and it seems that some objects are kept by the ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream from being collected by the GC. I used the Memory Analysis Tool in Eclipse to find out where the memory leak is located and found that there is a IdentityHashMap object that keeps the reference to te data being sent and received. I will like to find out a way around this issue on how to release this data or how to remove the reference this object keeps on my data preventing it from being collected. The memory heap I'm working with is pretty big for a cell phone 64M, and if I try the same with big chunks of data it works fine, as long as I don't run it for very long.

Comment: The IdentityHashMap is likely used by the Serialization/Deserialization code to keep a reference on already processed objects in order to prevent an endless loop because of circular references. I don't think your question can be answered unless you post some code.

Comment: IdentityHashMap is part of ObjectOutputStream cannot give you code of that, neither can change how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: Are you doing a "reset()" at any point?

Object streams remember every object written to them unless you reset them.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work. But now I'm facing issues while running the reset method in the ObjectInputStream object I have, it throws an IOException everytime I decided to run it, therefore I'm having data loss because of that.

Comment: SUGGESTION: just do an "ios.close()" on your ObjectInputStreams (when you're done with the entire stream);  "reset()" your ObjectOutputStreams.

Comment: Nailed it, the solution is so easy...reset the OutputStreams on both ends. Thank you very much.